# Exporting output of expansion of polynominal as rows

Tags: export

As usual text file output of e.g.

`Export["test.txt", Expand[(a + b + c)^3]]`

is

```
a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 3 a b^2 + b^3 + 3 a^2 c + 6 a b c + 3 b^2 c + 3 a c^2 + 3 b c^2 + c^3
```

When I open with a text editor, the format of this output is one column and one row.
I need each item as rows like in below with or without "+" (I gave an example without "+") for further use.

```
a^3
3 a^2 b
3 a b^2
b^3
3 a^2 c
6 a b c
3 b^2 c 
3 a c^2
3 b c^2
c^3
```

Is there a way to exporting the output as rows in Mathematica?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Export["test.txt", Expand[(a + b + c)^3]/.Plus->List ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply. However, I have received a error `$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of a^3`.

Comment: Try it again with a fresh kernel!

Comment: On v12.2.0-Win7-x64, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJLNm.png).

Comment: @Syed I added what I see in v12.2 Windows11

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I misread the question where parts were required on separate lines. Everything's good.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks refreshing kernel solved the problem and everything is OK now.